# Can you escape from two lions in a closed arena?

Tags: game-theory, recreational-mathematics

You're at the center of a circular arena. A pair of lions are at the border, planning to catch you. One of them moves as fast as you, but the other moves slower than you. The three of you are confined to move in the arena (border included). A lion catches you if your distance is $0$.

There are three possibilities:

1. You can move wisely and never get caught.
2. You get caught eventually.
3. It depends on how fast the slow lion moves.

**Which one is correct, and why?**

---

Some background: it is known that one lion as fast as you never catches you, and two of such lions always do. As a curious side note, according to the British mathematician [Béla Bollobás](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-19533-4_12), after the former case was first asked in 1930s by the mathematician Richard Rado, its wrong solution (that the lion can catch the man) remained the standard answer for about twenty years, until in the 50s the mathematician Abram S. Besicovitch found an unexpected solution (that the man never gets caught).

I initially asked this as a puzzle [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115662/can-you-escape-from-two-lions), and have not received good answers so far.

Comment: I would say it depends somewhat on how fast the slow lion moves. Because, if the slow lion has zero maximal speed then you can employ the existing solution for the problem with one lion in a smaller arena.  But I guess if the slow lion has to have positive maximal speed, then  you get caught and it does not matter anymore how fast the slow lion can run, because there is one point of time from which on the distance between the fast lion and you is very small compared to the maximal speed of the slow lion.

Comment: @Numa It turns out you'll never be caught with one fast lion + finitely many slow lions.